# Is an indicator function composed with an Lp function defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is linked to a previous question I had asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924619/defining-a-push-forward-image-measure-operator).

Let $L^{p}(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ be the space of equivalence classes of $p$- integrable functions on $[0,1]$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Take $h\in L^{p}$ and let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Is the mapping $B\mapsto \mathbb{1}_{B}(h(x))$, where $B\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, defined on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

If the map is defined, where is it equal to 1? I am thinking that if $B$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{1}_{B}(h(x))=0$ since functions in $h(x)$ will take values outside of $B$ for measure zero sets. And $\mathbb{1}_{B}(h(x))=1$ only if $B = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's certainly not defined pointwise,  but might it be defined in an "almost everywhere" sense?

Comment: Is "set valued" a mistake?

Comment: Yes set-valued was a mistake...fixed, thanks